# Using XZing to scan ISBN in JAVA

Tags: java, barcode

I want to scan ISBN (EAN13) using [XZing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). Here is my function:

```
private String readBarcode(String fileName) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        BufferedImage image = null;
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = null;
        Result result = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
            int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
            RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels);
            bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }
        EAN13Reader reader = new EAN13Reader();
        try {

            result = reader.decode(bitmap);

            System.out.println("Decoded image successfully, result was : '" + result.getText() + "'");
            return result.getText();

        } catch (FormatException | NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I tried to scan the following image several times:
[ISBN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyLw1.jpg)

But I only receive a NotFound Exception. Did I forget something?

Comment: Please put the exception stack trace, and say which libraries you've used in the project.

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing this is the library. I will provide the trace later.

Comment: @Omar com.google.zxing.NotFoundException is the only stacktrace output I get. XZings online version using the java lib is working with the same image.